# What's $H_6({RP}^3\times {RP}^3)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In ${RP}^3\times {RP}^3$, $d(e^3\times e^3)$=0, since $d(e^3)$=0. So in this sense, $H_6({RP}^3\times {RP}^3)$ should be $Z$, however, by Kunneth Formula, we can get it should be in the form of ⊕ $(Tor(H_k(RP^m), H_{i−k−1}(RP^3)))$, which should be the product of $Z_2$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why don't you 1st just compute the top dim co-homology(by using Kunneth formula), and then use Universal Coefficient theorem to compute the homology, and make it less complicated in that sense.

Comment: Of course one can compute it using Künneth and what not, but your space is an orientable connected closed manifold of dimension 6, so $H_6$ has to be free of rank $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Kunneth formula,

$$ H_6(RP^3 \times RP^3)= \bigoplus_{i+j=6} H_i(RP^3) \otimes H_j(RP^3) \oplus \bigoplus_{i+j=5} Tor(H_i(RP^3),H_j(RP^3)) $$

where every homology group is taken with integer coefficients. I'm not sure what version of Kunneth you are appealing to, but there is a problem if you have omitted the first summand above. At any rate, we obtain $H_6 = \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $S^3\to S^3/\{\pm 1\} = \mathbb{RP}^3$ is a double cover, $\mathbb{RP}^3\times \mathbb{RP}^3$ is a compact, orientable space. Thus $H_6(\mathbb{RP}^3 \times \mathbb{RP}^3) = \mathbb{Z}$. If you want to use the Kuenneth formula, the only $H_*(\mathbb{RP}^3)$ with torsion is $H_1(\mathbb{RP}^3) = \mathbb{Z}_2$, so none of the $\operatorname{Tor}(H_*(\mathbb{RP}^3) \otimes H_*(\mathbb{RP}^3))$ terms contribute to $H_6(\mathbb{RP}^3\times \mathbb{RP}^3)$.

Comment: How do you get from a double cover that the manifold is orientable? Every non-orientable manifold has a double cover!

Comment: This particular double cover preserves the orientation on $S^3$; since we're an odd sphere, $-1$ preserves the fundamental class.

Comment: Well, my point was that it is in all likelyhood useful to edit your answer to explain that.